# Error 504 on loading a picture using Picasso

Tags: android, kotlin, https, picasso, http-status-code-504

I'm trying to load a picture into CircleImageView from a URL which I get from an API call. The URL of the image is working when I paste it into the browser but Picasso is unable to load it into the view.
The image URL is an https URL. For some reason, I can't share the image URL.

If anyone has faced the same issue or know the solution to this please help.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1896

Answer (score -1):

Since it seems that's a known issue of Picasso; if you are into Kotlin use [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil), otherwise [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).